# Qt for Python: What is the usefulness of the Slot() decorator?

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyside2

I use Qt for Python for a while now and find myself often asking: What is the usefulness of the Slot() decorator? If I connect to a signal the [documentation](https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_for_Python_Signals_and_Slots#New_syntax:_Signal.28.29_and_Slot.28.29) says I should decorate my callable function with the `Slot()` decorator. But is there any computational necessity or advantage in doing so? The following example connects two slots to the "pressed"-signal of a button. Both functions will work perfectly fine.

```
self.btn.pressed.connect(self.on_btn_pressed1)
self.btn.pressed.connect(self.on_btn_pressed2)

@Slot()
def on_btn_pressed1:
    print("Hello")

def on_btn_pressed2:
    print("World")
```

Comment: The documentation gives a hint: "Unlike the Signal() class, to overload a function, you don't pass every variation as tuple or list. Instead, you have to define a new decorator for every different signature." It then provides examples where you have more than one `@Slot` decorator for a function.